# Что делать если код срабатывает 1 раз, а потом выдает ошибку?

Tags: python, selenium

```
def click_to_element(self):
    while True:
        try:

            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/button/div[3]/div').click()
            sleep(3)
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screen.png")
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                '#modal-portal > div.modal.below-md\:p-0.bg-\[\#1d2445\].md\:bg-transparent.active > div.modal__content.w-\[52\.5rem\].overflow-visible.below-md\:min-h-full.max-h-none > div > div.flex.flex-col.md\:flex-row.gap-10.mt-12.mb-20 > button.btn.btn--green.grow').click()
            sleep(5)

            driver.switch_to.default_content()

            iframe1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                          'iframe[src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&v=vP4jQKq0YJFzU6e21-BGy3GP&k=6Lc3qPIUAAAAAFGLONQbUEAOgbdU8WTiC3HpRqKI"]')

            driver.switch_to.frame(iframe1)

            sleep(5)
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                "#rc-imageselect > div.rc-footer > div.rc-controls > div.primary-controls > div.rc-buttons > div.button-holder.help-button-holder").click()
            print("Clicked!")
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            sleep(7)
            driver.refresh()
            sleep(1800)


        except:
            if driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                   '#modal-portal > div.modal.below-md\:p-0.bg-\[\#1d2445\].md\:bg-transparent.active > div.modal__content.w-\[52\.5rem\].overflow-visible.below-md\:min-h-full.max-h-none > div > div.flex.flex-col.md\:flex-row.gap-10.mt-12.mb-20 > div'):
                print('Not Clicked!')
                driver.switch_to.default_content()
                sleep(7)
                driver.refresh()
                sleep(1800)
```

Код почему-то не срабатывает второй раз после задержки в 1800 секунд, и выдает такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обьясните мне что не так?

Comment: Вывести куда-нибудь страницу и посмотреть, что там.

Comment: @CrazyElf через каждые 1800 секунд элемент появляется, первый раз селениум его видит, а второй раз нет. Почему так может проичходить?

Comment: нельзя в обработчике ошибок вызывать другую ошибку, вот Вы пишите `except: if driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR` а есть уверенность что у Вас не возникает тут ошибки? любой подобный доступ нужно оборачивать в `try except`